# Where can I find a will that passed property to municipality with restrictive covenants?

Tags: real-estate, property, wills

The will of George H. Hermann passed property from his estate to the City of Houston. Some of the transfers, included clauses like the following,

> in the city of Houston, Harris County, Texas, for the benefit of the poor, indigent and infirm residents of the City of Houston all of

This excerpt is in [Gredig v. Sterling, 47 F.2d 832 (5th Cir. 1931)](https://casetext.com/case/gredig-v-sterling). Where can I find the will unabridged so I can see what restrictive covenants it places it on other properties devised to the city?

Comment: I would expect any restrictive covenant on real estate to be recorded. I start at the GIS/tax office to identify the plat numbers, then I go next door to the Register of Deeds and ask for everything related to that plat number.  Your state may vary but probably not by a lot.  The tax plat data may be online (but the online UX generally expects a mailing/street address; I deal with a lot of plats without that so I have to talk to GIS).  The deeds will usually not be online - it's bulky, rarely asked for, and it being online would invite trouble.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Not far from the mark, but the real estate records won't be organized by plat number. They will be organized in a grantor-grantee index that you have to work back on step at a time. Often people hire title companies to gather them up for them, or hire members of an independent paralegal profession called "land men" when do the same thing.